# Is it possible to define extra details in the callerContext of a Cognito pre-token lambda call?

Tags: amazon-cognito

In Cognito, I have a pretoken generation hook setup and my lambda receives this

```
{
  "callerContext": {
    "clientId": "abcde12345" // some hash,
    ...
  },
  "request": {
    "userAttributes": {
      "email": "foo@bar.com",
      "sub": "someUserID",
      ...
    },
    ...
  },
  ...
}
```

I would like to be able to determine what claims to assign this user, not by the user attributes, but by the app the user is using to login.
Naturally, I could just use `callContext.clientId` but that can change when an app client is recreated. Is there a way to use a custom string from the callerContext? e.g

```
"callerContext": {
    "clientId": "abcde12345" // some hash,
    "appName": "FoobarGame"
  }
```

Is it possible to define this custom string in the Cognito App client instead of relying on the cognito Id?(which can change upon recreation).

Comment: I guess your concern here is to avoid the code changes, based on the changes in client id. correct?

Comment: @sampathDilhan correct.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is doable. At least in the [document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-identity-pools-working-with-aws-lambda-triggers.html#cognito-user-pools-lambda-trigger-syntax-shared), they haven't mentioned a way to use a custom string within the `callerContext`.

As your requirement is: to avoid the code changes, based on the changes in client id, I would suggest to use lambda environment variables.

So we can specify the client Id as an environment variable. Then in the code, retrieve it from there. With that approach, way we don't have to change the code and only the environment variable value.

Would that work for you?

Comment: The problem with lambda env var is, in the event that you deploy your stack with CDK, there becomes a cyclical dependency. One that cannot be solved by Multistage dependency CDK deployments.